# Jira -Python update issues takes very long time

Tags: python, performance, jira, jira-rest-api

I am using python with jira package and writing a simple script that will create or update all the existing issues for a project on my company's server.
Creating multiple issues via python is very fast and i can create 100 issues within 30 or seconds. But the problem is when i want to update those issues. When i update issues it takes a very long time probably 4 or 5 minutes for updating 100 issues. I am getting the **InsecureRequestWarnings** warning. I tried to disable warnings as well but still the program is very slow when it comes to updating the issues. How can i make updating issues faster?
NOTE: Each issue update takes more than 3.1 secs.

```
from jira import *
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings() #Comment this to see warnings
options = {'server': 'Company Server', 'verify': False}

jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('username', "password"))

nameOfProjects = "Project name from jira"

issuesJira = jira.search_issues(jql_str='project= 
"{}"'.format(nameOfProjects),fields='summary, key,type,status', startAt=0, 
maxResults=1000)

test = 0
for issue in issuesJira:
   issue.update(notify=False, fields={
                                    'summary' :'some Text',
                                    'description': 'some Text- ' +str(test),
                                     'priority': {"name": 'High'},
                                    'components': [{'name': 'TestMode'}],
                                    "issuetype": {"name": 'Requirement'},
                                    'fixVersions': [{'name': 'test'}]})
  print('issue is updated-', test)
   test = test +1
print('END')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also experiencing this issue.

It seems there may be a bug in the python API that adds a 4s sleep in the update method.
https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/622

Since this bug has been open for almost 2 years, I think it's time for a fork!

Answer (score 0):

Is username in the first user directory that is configured in Jira user management? That can affect authentication times.

Does the project have a complex permission scheme or issue security scheme?

What changes if you only update one field such as Summary? Does that change the timing?

I would expect about 1s/issue update in many installations

Comment: Yes the username is in the first user directory. As i said i can create new issues within the same script via same username very quickly and efficiently.
Yes, the project has complex scheme but i don't think it can effect that much when it comes to updating only.
In my case, i have more than 2000 requirements on the jira and once a week minimum 100 requirements are changed and that has to be updated via my script. If i update only one (1) field of an issue e.g. the description only, it still takes more than 3.1 secs for each issue.

Comment: What about updating the same issue using a browser. Is that also slow?

Comment: The server is quicker. When i do from server it takes less time.